# How do I change part of the text of a tooltip title

Tags: tooltip, title

How do I highlight bold "important" within the title attribute of the tooltip?

I have tried to embed `<bold></bold>` within the string but didn't work.

I will also like to break line when the title is lengthy.

```
<script>
$('[name="acc"]').attr('title', "This is a very important topic");
</script>
```

There are several tool tips like this in the HTML body:

```
<i aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" name="acc">
<span class="iconify" data-icon="mdi:numeric-1-circle"></span></i>
```